# Parametrizing a tangent

Tags: parametrization

Find parametric equations of the straight line tangent to the following space curve at the point $P(−3,−9,0)$ on the curve.
$$r(t)=(8t^2+63t+46)i+(2t^3-98t-9)j+\frac{70\sqrt3}{\pi}(1+2\cos(\frac{4\pi t}{21}))k$$

I found the tangent equation as 
$$x(t)=-71+15t$$
$$y(t)=-585+388t$$
$$z(t)=\frac{210\sqrt3}{\pi}$$
But I have to paramterize in a way such as 
$$x(t)=~-3- 49s$$
$$y(t)=-9+196s$$
$$z(t)= ~-40s$$
How should I do it?

Comment: I do not know why you are asking that. It should not be difficult. For example, put $t = -49s/15 + 144/97$.

Comment: What about $z(t)$? Should it remain the same value?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you come up with your “tangent equation?”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\vec r(t)=\left(8 t^2+63 t+46,2 t^3-98 t-9,\frac{70 \sqrt{3} \left(2 \cos \left(\frac{4 \pi  t}{21}\right)+1\right)}{\pi }\right)$$
gives the point $P(−3,−9,0)$ for $t=-7$

we have $$\vec r\,'(t)=\left(16 t+63,6 t^2-98,-\frac{80 \sin \left(\frac{4 \pi  t}{21}\right)}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$
plugging $t=-7$ we get $\vec t=(-49,\;196,\;-40)$

the tangent line has parametric equations $(x,y,z)=(−3,−9,0)+t(-49,\;196,\;-40)$

that is

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 x=-3-49 t \\
 y=-9+196 t \\
 z=-40 t \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

Hope this helps

Comment: Oh I misinterpreted the question.